# Curve bevel, both built in and using another curve not uniform in thickness

Tags: bevel, bezier-curves

Im trying to make a pipe using single edge, converted to curve, and then bevel it to add some thickness. but the result turns out weird.

as in the picture, the vertical section of the pipe is in uniform thickness, but the horizontal segment is much more thicker. This happen whether using built in bevel selector or using a bezier circle as bevel object.

how can i make it all uniform in thickness?

[image: curve bevel not uniform in thickness]

Comment: You've scaled your curve in Z in object mode. Ctrl-A > Apply Scale will fix that one. (BTW, you _might_ not need a bevel object in this case? Unless you need to edit it, you could use the curve's native profile )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must have scaled it on the *Z* axis. Select your curve and <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd> > *Apply Scale*